# nameExpression: option named 'nameExpression' is not supported

Tags: spring-xd

I am trying to deploy one stream in springXD.

```
stream create --name myfilestream --definition "http --port=9000 | file --nameExpression=payload.trim()" --deploy
```

But the error I am getting is like below:

```
Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Error with option(s) for module file of type sink:
    nameExpression: option named 'nameExpression' is not supported
```

When I remove `--nameExpression=payload.trim()`,I am able to create stream..

Any suggestion..where is the problem..

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using? That wasn't added to file sink until 1.2.

Use 1.2.0.RELEASE.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2717

Also, when using `nameExpression`, you also need `dirExpression`.